# How to read data from using chank size and process in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am using spring batch 5. I need to read and process chank data using custom query. When job started it get data from database using chank until complete data. That means if chank size 1000 then it read first 1000 and process, next 1000 read and process concurrently. I have tried bellow like

1. Repository:

   ```
   @Transactional
   @Repository
   public interface TransactionRepo extends JpaRepository<TransactionEntity, Long> {
       @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION WHERE STATUS =1 FOR UPDATE ", nativeQuery = true)
       List<TransactionEntity> getbKashTransaction();
   }
   ```
2. Here is the reader

   ```
       @Slf4j
   public class ReaderStep1 implements ItemReader<TransactionEntity> {
       private Iterator<TransactionEntity> iterator;
       private TransactionSPcall transactionSPcall;
       public ReaderStep1(TransactionRepo transactionRepo, TransactionSPcall transactionSPcall) {
           this.transactionSPcall = transactionSPcall;
          List<TransactionEntity> list = transactionRepo.getbKashTransaction();

           if(!list.isEmpty()){

               this.iterator = list.iterator();

           }
       }

       @Override
       public TransactionEntity read() {

           return (iterator != null && iterator.hasNext()) ? iterator.next() : null;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Processor

   ```
       @Slf4j
   public class ProcessorStep1 implements ItemProcessor<TransactionEntity, TransactionEntity> {
       @Override
       public TransactionEntity process(TransactionEntity item) throws Exception {

           return item;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Writer:

   ```
       @Slf4j
   public class WriterStep1 implements ItemWriter<TransactionEntity> {


       @Override
       public void write(Chunk<? extends TransactionEntity> chunk) {

           chunk.forEach(item -> {

           });      
       }
   }
   ```
5. Configuration

   ```
       @Configuration
   public class BatchBean {
       @Bean
       public ProcessorStep1 batchProcessorStep1() {
           return new ProcessorStep1();
       }
       @Bean
       public WriterStep1 batchWriterStep1() {
           return new WriterStep1();
       }

   }
   ```
6. Job Configuration:

   ```
           @Component
       @RequiredArgsConstructor
       @Slf4j
       public class BksashJob {
           private final TransactionRepo transactionRepo;
           private final ProcessorStep1 batchProcessorStep1;
           private final WriterStep1 batchWriterStep1;
           private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
           private final JobRepository jobRepository;

           @Autowired
           private TransactionSPcall transactionSPcall;

           public Job createStp1(){
               return new JobBuilder("BK-STEP1", jobRepository)
                       .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                       .start(step1())
                       .build();



           }

           private Step step1(){

               return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                       .<TransactionEntity, TransactionEntity> chunk(1000, transactionManager)
                       .reader(new ReaderStep1(transactionRepo, transactionSPcall))
                       .processor(batchProcessorStep1)
                       .writer(batchWriterStep1)
                       .build();
           }

       }
   ```

To read chank size data without overlapping , what I need to change my code?

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

The reader you shared will read all records in a list in memory and return them from that list. There is no hint to the database driver to load only a subset of the results.

Based on the reader and the query you shared, I believe you should be able leverage one of the database cursor/paging item readers provided by Spring Batch (for example, use a `JdbcCusrorItemReader` and set the `fetchSize` parameter as needed).